# Unable to publish application in Google Play using Send_SMS

Tags: android, xamarin

My Android application required to access `"sms_send"` permission which is stated on my application project manifest, that's why I checked
the following permission (Default `SMS` handler and Default Assistant handler) from the Google Permission Declaration Form. But I tried to publish many times still my publish won't succeed. This error message appeared:

> App rejected.  "Your recent app submission was rejected for violating
>   the Permissions policy. Before submitting your app for another review,
>   read through the policy and make sure your app is in compliance"

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read policy for permissions and make sure your app meets requirements. Also update your privacy policy url.

Comment: If SEND_SMS is not in your manifest.xml then for sure it is in your 3rd party library attached with the application. So you need to remove that permission to make working

Answer (score 3):

Yes call history permission and sms permission became restrictive since last October, my application is also delisted because of this. Google now only allows default SMS app or companion app to use sms. It is not your fault.

Comment: yes agreed, what is really frustrating, google play doesn't tell you the exact reason why you are rejected, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

had you checked this page already?

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?hl=en

I don't know what your app's main category part, but many apps were rejected after google's restricts rule change.

hope this answer may help for you

Comment: yes I've checked it already base from the core function that i used, since that i am using the send_sms, read_sms functions, i've checked both the Default SMS handler and Default Assistant handler, still, Google play rejected my publish, i don't know now what to do. thanks for your help anyway really appreciated.